# Play caller a radio stream with asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk, phpagi

I using asterisk with php scripts that use php-agi.
What I need to do is to play the caller a radio stream, the stream is coming from dynamic url (It can be changed by the owner of the line).
I try MOH (not so good).
I try to use MP3Player `$agi-exec("MP3Player", $streamUrl);` but I get this error "sh: 1: MP3Player: not found"

I use asterisk 1.6

Did any one have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AGI exec  command will run MP3Plyaer asterisk COMMAND, which never was created. You should use EAGI script or use moh class with stream.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-eagi/

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-config-musiconholdconf/#StreamradiousingMPlayerforMOH

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
About MOH, I try it and get this error in the log file:
"2020-06-14T06:54:41.899334978Z [Jun 14 06:54:41] WARNING[58]: res_musiconhold.c:794 monmp3thread: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
2020-06-14T06:54:41.935436937Z MOH: exec failed: Permission denied".

Regarding asterisk EAGI, can you please elaborate, please, I never use it.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: "Permission denied"

Comment: Thanks, I think I fix the permission, but I don't hear anything.
How can I check that the "moh.sh" file is running, because I don't hear anything.
And about the EAGI, do you have any examples?

Comment: debug is offtopic on SO. examples available on first link